# Why are DHCP leases not included in DHCP Log?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log, dhcp-server

Running Windows Server 2008r2.  DHCP Logging is enabled (Server Manager, Roles, DHCP Server, , IPv4, Properties, General, Enable DHCP Audit Logging).

In the DHCP event log (Event Viewer, Custom Views, Server Roles, DHCP Server) I see events for the DHCP server starting, but new DHCP address leases are not logged.

How can I enable the logging to include new leases?

Answer (score 2):

The DHCP logs are located at `%windir%\System32\Dhcp`.

Comment: I want to create a task triggered by a DHCP lease. I know how do do that from events in the Event Viewer. The logs in %windir%\System32\Dhcp are apparently different.  Is it possible to open the DHCP logs %windir%\System32\Dhcp in a way that can create an event?

Comment: I tried to access the files in %windir%\System32\Dhcp, but they are locked by another process and cannot be opened.  What is the program that is intended to view these logs?  I can't see any way to open them in the Event Viewer

Comment: EventSentry (including the free light edition) can monitor DHCP logs in real time, and you can trigger actions based on certain text being logged to the DHCP file(s) - more info at http://www.eventsentry.com. The files shouldn't be locked by the DHCP server service, you should at least be able to read them. Did you try to open the files with administrative permissions?